# write output of print_r in a txt file. PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Print array to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628798/print-array-to-a-file)

How can I write the ouput (for example when I use an array), in a file?, I was trying with this:

```
    ...
print_r($this->show_status_redis_server());
$status_redis = ob_get_contents();
fwrite($file, $status_redis);
    ...
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`print_r()` has a second parameters that if passed as `TRUE` returns the output as a string.

```
$output = print_r($data, true);
file_put_contents('file.txt', $output);
```

You could even cosinder using `var_export` function, as it provides better information about data types. From `print_r` you can't tell if the variable is NULL of FALSE, but `var_export` lets use see exactly the data type of a variable.

Answer (score 4):

[`print_r($expression [, bool $return = false ])`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) has optional parameter that identifies you want to return string or echo one.

```
$str = print_r($desiredVariable, true);
fwrite($handle, $str);
```

Also I'd use [`file_put_contents`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
$content = print_r($yourVar, true);
file_put_contents('file.log', $content);
```