# How to convert .po to PHP array (Zend Framework) with Translate Toolkit?

Tags: php, zend-framework, internationalization, gettext, po

I am trying to use [po2php](http://docs.translatehouse.org/projects/translate-toolkit/en/latest/commands/php2po.html) to convert my .po file to Zend php translations array.

I am simply trying this: `$ po2php translations.po translations.php`, but this results in an error that I do not understand: `po2php: warning: Couldn't handle input file translations.po: don't know what to do with input format .po, no template file`.

I do not know what a template file is an why should I provide it?

UPDATE: I also tried `$ po2php translations.po translations.php -t messages.pot`, but this does not help me, it shows pretty much the same error: `po2php: warning: Couldn't handle input file translations.po: don't know what to do with input format .po, template format .pot`.

Comment: Why not use the Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext (http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.translate.adapter.html) to use you .po/.mo files directly ?

Comment: It's simply a requirement for a project I'm working on. Historical reasons...

Comment: Sorry, can't help then...   :(

Answer (score 0):

You could also try out the pear package [File_Gettext](http://pear.php.net/package/File_Gettext). Read more here: https://github.com/pear/File_Gettext

The code would look like this (Not tested):

```
include_once 'File/Gettext/PO.php';

$poFile = new File_Gettext_PO();
$poFile->load('PATH_TO/translations.po');

print_r($poFile->strings);
```

`$poFile->strings` should contain the content of the po file as associative array. Next you need a function to output this array in a file. Take a look at the second answer here: [Print array to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628798/print-array-to-a-file)