# How to edit and save custom config files in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, configuration-files

I am creating simple web application in Laravel 4. I have backend for managing applications content. As a part of backend i want to have UI to manage applications settings. I want my configuration variables to be stored in file [FOLDER: **/app/config/customconfig.php**].

I was wondering if there's any possibility in Laravel how to have custom config file, which can be managed/updated thru backend UI?

Answer (score 10):

I did it like this ...

```
config(['YOURKONFIG.YOURKEY' => 'NEW_VALUE']);
$fp = fopen(base_path() .'/config/YOURKONFIG.php' , 'w');
fwrite($fp, '<?php return ' . var_export(config('YOURKONFIG'), true) . ';');
fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll have to extend the Fileloader, but it's very simple:

```
class FileLoader extends \Illuminate\Config\FileLoader
{
    public function save($items, $environment, $group, $namespace = null)
    {
        $path = $this->getPath($namespace);

        if (is_null($path))
        {
            return;
        }

        $file = (!$environment || ($environment == 'production'))
            ? "{$path}/{$group}.php"
            : "{$path}/{$environment}/{$group}.php";

        $this->files->put($file, '<?php return ' . var_export($items, true) . ';');
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
$l = new FileLoader(
    new Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem(), 
    base_path().'/config'
);

$conf = ['mykey' => 'thevalue'];

$l->save($conf, '', 'customconfig');
```

Comment: Thank you. Instead of base_path() , I used app_path().

Comment: Hello @Antonio where to put new extended class means in which folder? i am currently using laravel 5.5 please help.

Answer (score 5):

Based upon @Batman answer with respect to current version (from 5.1 to 6.x):

```
config(['YOUR-CONFIG.YOUR_KEY' => 'NEW_VALUE']);
$text = '<?php return ' . var_export(config('YOUR-CONFIG'), true) . ';';
file_put_contents(config_path('YOUR-CONFIG.php'), $text);
```

Answer (score 2):

Afiak there is no built-in functionality for manipulating config files. I see 2 options to achieve this:

- You can store your custom config in your database and override the default config at runtime with `Config::set('key', 'value');` But be aware that

> Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests. @see: http://laravel.com/docs/configuration

- Since config files are simple php arrays, it's easy to read, manipulate and [write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628798/print-array-to-a-file) them. So with a little custom code this should be done quickly.

In general I'd prefer the first option. Overriding config files can might cause some troubles when it comes to version control, deployment, automated testing, etc. But as always, this strongly depends on your project setup.