# Write to laravel 5 config files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for a way to write to laravel 5 configuration files, in a cleaner and easier way then using the good old `str_replace`.

There are laravel 4 solutions:
[How to edit and save custom config files in Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25711296/how-to-edit-and-save-custom-config-files-in-laravel)
and: 
https://github.com/daftspunk/laravel-config-writer

But this is not working in laravel 5.

Comment: What from those provided solutions didn't work? Did you encounter an error, did it not update the file?

Comment: Those solutions do not work with laravel 5. Laravel 5 has other method signatures. FileLoader is no more under the Config namespace but `Translation` now. The config/Repository has other constructor arguments, etc. etc.

Comment: Solution I've used at the moment: set the settings on runtime in the ioc container.

Answer (score 1):

From version 5.1 you are able to do next for changing any config file:

```
config(['YOUR-CONFIG.YOUR_KEY' => 'NEW_VALUE']);
$text = '<?php return ' . var_export(config('YOUR-CONFIG'), true) . ';';
file_put_contents(config_path('YOUR-CONFIG.php'), $text);
```