# Display the array value to the txt file

Tags: php

I have an array something like below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => IA62b066
    [1] => IAca99de
    [2] => IAafed13
    [3] => IA49882c
    [4] => IA5c9872
    [5] => IA39b3e1
```

I want to export the only the value from this array to text file. Txt file should display data like this.

```
IA62b066
IAca99de
IAafed13
IA49882c
IA5c9872
IA39b3e1
```

I have tried many ways but I could not solve it.

```
file_put_contents("output/$fileName.txt", print_r($array, true));
```

Can anybody please help me solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will create `test.txt` file in the directory of php script with the content of the array.

```
<?php

$input = [
    'IA62b066',
    'IAca99de',
    'IAafed13',
    'IA49882c',
    'IA5c9872',
    'IA39b3e1'
];

$filePath = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'test.txt';
$content = implode(PHP_EOL, $input);
file_put_contents($filePath, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
$myfile = fopen("newfile.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
foreach($your_array as $value){
   fwrite($myfile, $value . '\n');
}
fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: is there any other solution in php to solve this without loop.

Comment: @nas It looks like it is possible but you already tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628798/print-array-to-a-file